# PHP include in .HTML file not getting parsed

Tags: php, html, nginx, server-side-rendering, ssi

Migrated from Apache (Godaddy) to Nginx (DigitalOcean), the PHP code below in index.html does not work and as a result, the footer portion of the site disappeared. It works fine on the old server.

```
<? include("includes/copyright.php") ?>
```

Server details:

Ubuntu 20.04
PHP 7.14.15
Nginx 1.18.0

```
sudo systemctl list-units 'php*'
```

[image]

[image: /etc/nginx/mysite.com.conf]

[image]

Comment: so you put php code in the .html file?

Comment: It's probably including it correctly, but not processing it because the "parent" page is .html, not .php.

Comment: Can you post your nginx config? Are you using php-fpm? Assuming you are, you could adjust the extensions defined in security.limit_extensions to include .html

Comment: @forloops nginx conf uploaded.

Comment: @droopsnoot this was working fine on the old Apache server. It stopped working after migrating it to Nginx

Comment: @forloops - yes

Comment: Many web servers can be told which file extensions they should parse for PHP, ASP and so on, so maybe the old Apache server was configured differently. That rather looks like answer @forloops has given below.

Answer (score 0):

in your nginx config, update line starting with `location ~ \.php(/|$) {` with:

```
location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
```

then restart services. This will allow your html files to be parsed through php

If passing to fastcgi does not work, you can add a directive to your php-fpm config:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html
```

Comment: Do I need to start any other server besides nginx?

Comment: Updated " /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com.conf " with the above, restarted the server but still, same problem.

Added "security.limit_extensions = .php .html" to /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf then restarted server, but still, no luck!